# NewtonSoft JSON serializer and UTF8 support

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a simple method using NewtonSoft's JSON serializer and I love it (simple, returns formatted JSON).  However I can't seem to get it to properly serialize UTF8 characters (they show up as a question mark i.e. '?') that are found in strings within an object.

The code I'm using is:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { });
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show. Show how you read/write your json string to disk/network

Comment: LB the code creating the object isn't the issue.  Verified using tests like Console.WriteLine(val).  Johan - just using simple Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @haxor You posted the most irrelated part of your code. If  you are sure about your code then why do you  ask a question here?

Comment: You were correct.  The issue was elsewhere.  Sorry to waste your time.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @haxor: you should post your fix. I'm having the same problem here

Comment: @quamis this was so long ago that I don't recall what it was.  Happy to give you a hand if you like, just send me a private message or start a chat

Comment: @haxor I've fixed in the meantime. For future reference, I had to do `WebClient net = new WebClient(); net.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're serializing to a string and not to a byte array, you're not dealing with any character encodings (like utf-8) at this stage.

You'll have to find out where it's actually converted to/from UTF-8 and fix the problem there.

Comment: I just stumbled over the same problem in a legacy code base, so - thanks for your help; But normally they (the serialization libraries) should deal with this using JSON notation: german "äpfel" would become "\u00e4pfel" for example. In my opinion it's not correct to let the webclient handle this problem.